# StrongLoop AccessToken Create is for Public

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

If I were to know user ID of another user and URL (`<host>/api/AccessTokens/create`) , I can get access token for that user and fake his actions. Am I right ? Find following the standard ACL for AccessToken model from a default LoopBack Project. I am using above method instead of refresh token. Is there any better way ?

```
    "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "property": "create",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your model config file and set the **public false** for the AccessToken class.

```
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
```

AccessToken should never be exposed through api's, It should only be used internally by the user model.